# IPhone ios 5, recreate database on each simulator run?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, sqlite

How can i replace the database (with the one i am working on) in my app on each simulator run? (Still adding data and want to check that it looks good)

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working, still using the old database:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    dbname = @"animaldatabase.sql";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    dbpath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbname];

    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readAnimalsFromDatabase];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [animals count]];
}

- (void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbpath];
    if (success) {
     //return;
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dbpath error:nil];
    }

    NSString *dbPathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbname];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:dbpath error:nil];
}
```

Also where is the location for the iphone database? When my app copies the database into the iphone, where does it end up?

**UPDATE**

Added the loading code as well.

Senthilkumar:

I fail to see how this should solve the problem? Doesn't this just skip the copying or my database if it already exists?

What i want is to delete the database in my iphone app. Import the new database and then run it.

Comment: When performing these file manager operations, use the `error` parameter.  Create a `NSError* error;` beforehand, pass `&error` to the functions, then check it against `nil` afterwards.  That should show you if there's errors, and potentially help debugging.  If `error != nil`, then `[error localizedDescription]` should show you the error message.

Comment: Where is this error shown? I can see when i alter some parameters that it gets hit and that the [error localizedDescription]; gets triggered. But where does that show up? Not in the output/error/console area.

Comment: I added a half-answer below, so that I could show a more complete code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code instead of that.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
 databaseName=@"yourfileName.sqlite";
 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName]; 
[self checkAndCreateDatabase]; 

}
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase {

BOOL success;


NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

if(success) return;
else
    printf("NO File found");

NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

}
```

Comment: and set in your - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  function following lines     databaseName=@"yourfileName.sqlite";    
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

Comment: You can post additional code into your answer by **editing** it, which would make the code a bit more readable than when it's in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To help debug file manager operations, it helps to try and use the `error` parameter, like so:

```
NSError* error;
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:dbpath error: &error];
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"copyItemAtPath generated error=%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

If you do this, the error message will get written to your debugger console / standard output window.